# want to implement jtattoo look and feel, but not working

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I want to implement Acryl Look and Feel, it runs fine when i run file only, but when i run Main Project it returns the default l&F.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            /*if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
             * javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
             * break;
             * }*/
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");
         }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: you realizes that you are setting n-times?

Comment: Any errors/exceptions?

Comment: no errors or exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck the main class you set, for e.g login form can be a main class for a particular project.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to loop and setting n-times in your code.

Just in your Main Project `main()` put this line.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: what i want to realize you that you don't have it installed the one you want...so you have to put the jar in your classpath and then you can call     `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");`   without the loop!!

Comment: i have taken the jtattoo.jar file in my project library, then also it doesnt work

Comment: but do you set in your Main Project??